# How to create room account in docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I have read all the docs but i am not getting any link to create docuSign room account.

a direct link to create a docusign room account.Please suggest me docusign link , so i can create my room account.I want to create room

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately at this point of time (October 2023) you cannot create a Rooms account yourself.

[Following these instructions](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/rooms-api/rooms101/create-account/), the important part is that you have to email the DocuSign Rooms support team with your account information so that they'll add the Rooms feature to your developer account.

> Contact DocuSign to request a Rooms account via
> support-re@docusign.com. Include the following information: Your
> company’s name and address. Your developer account ID. To find your
> Account ID, log in to your eSignature developer account, then select
> your account portrait to access your profile. Copy the Account ID
> value that appears directly below your name in the displayed drop-down
> menu. Your API Account ID. To find your API Account ID, log in to your
> eSignature developer account and select Admin, then click Apps and
> Keys. Copy your API Account ID value. Your choice of whether to use
> Rooms for Mortgage or Rooms for Real Estate. If you aren’t sure which
> product you should select, note this in your email. DocuSign can help
> you determine which product is right for your business.

Comment: Thank you for guidance,  Can you suggest me a way to create a room through API integration.
I know about JWT token/Authorization code and getting accesss token for dtr.room.write scope, but i don't have room account so i am facing access denied error. Suggest me a path

Comment: Did you send an email to support-re@docusign.com ?

Comment: yes, waiting for response

Comment: You should be good now